# Financial time difference (in R)

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, finance

I am working with financial asset pricing data and I am interested in finding the time difference between the dates of two consecutive operations on the market.

A simple example could be:

- first operation -> client X buys stock A on 2020-01-**02** 09:00:00
- second operation -> client X buys stock B on 2020-01-**03** 09:00:00

Here is my problem:
I am looking for a function that computes the **FINANCIAL time difference** between this two datetime objects.

Hence, I am not interested in a simple calendar time difference (that can be computed in R using the well-known `difftime()` function), but in a time difference that considers the financial or trading day, that is (roughly speaking) a day that starts at 9.00 am and ends at 18.00 pm.

Therefore, this function should give a result of **9 hours** (if the unit reference is hour) to the simple example above, instead of *24 hours* as the usual calendar time difference would suggest.

A more complex version of this function would also take into account the market holidays and exclude weekends from computation.

Following an example using R

```
d1 <- as.POSIXct("2020-01-02 09:00:00", tz = "UTC")
d2 <- as.POSIXct("2020-01-03 09:00:00", tz = "UTC")

difftime(d2, d1, units = "hours")
```

This produce a time difference of 24 hours.
However, the **expected result** would be just **9 hours**, since the financial (or market trading) day ends on 2020-01-02 at 18.00 pm and starts again the day after at 9.00 am, hence there should be only 9 hours of trading between the two.

I mainly work in R, so I would appreciate if someone can give me some advice on that language, but if anyone knows something similar in other languages would also be very useful.

Thank you a lot for your help and time.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah I have added a simple reprex with R code. Hope this can help.